# Get Action name from Route Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I know if I want to get the current action I can use;

```
ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
```

However what if my route allowed `http://mydomain/this has spaces`

How would I get "`This Has Spaces`" rather than "`ThisHasSpaces`"?

Here is a snippet from my route table

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "ThisHasSpaces", // Route name
            "This Has Spaces", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "ThisHasSpaces", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Do you really get `ThisHasSpaces`?

Comment: Yes I do as that is the action name in the controller and my route table translates the spaces to the non-spaced version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your route looks like that there's nothing that can give you the original string (other than  `Request.Uri`) since you do not actually map the uri to a route parameter.

Since you hardcode the route you could add another value:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ThisHasSpaces", // Route name
        "This Has Spaces", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "ThisHasSpaces", orgstring = "This Has Spaces", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

And fetch it:

```
ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["orgstring"]
```